# How do i run android comaptibity package samples

Tags: android

I want to run the samples given in android compatibility package v4. I imported the project into eclipse but i get the following error com.example.android.supportv4.R cannot be resolved. How do i run the samples given

Comment: Did you figure it out? I can't get my R to resolve either now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the Target SDK is level 13.  Once you target that, the resources get included.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, it wasn't enough for me to just set target=android-13. Moved all the ./src files away, then commented out `service android:name=".content.LocalServiceBroadcaster$LocalService" android:stopWithTask="true"` tag in the manifest, and R got generated. Moved sources back, they compiled. `android:stopWithTask` didn't get recognized, though.

Comment: This is because stopWithTask attribute is available only from 14 API level from [here][1]


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#stopWithTask

Answer (score 1):

You should put android-support-v13.jar in your build path instead of android-support-v4.jar and it will work